# Android detect if there is colour white on image and display toast

Tags: android, android-image, android-toast

I have a static image that has a black background and some white colours on. All I just need to know is how to detect white colours on an image and then display a toast message. Or in other words, if there is a colour white on image then display a toast message. I have been researching for a couple of hours but it seems of no luck. Can someone kind here help me please.

Comment: Did you mean an image you put in res/drawable/ folder?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, you need to get the file path of your image from sdcard.

```
String baseDir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
String filePath = baseDir + "/your_file_name.jpg";

Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath);
```

Now you have a bitmap. You can check every pixels in it.

```
int w = bitmap.getWidth();
int h = bitmap.getHeight();
for(int i =  0; i < w; i++){
    for(int j = 0; j < h; j++) {
        int pixel =  bitmap.getPixel(i, j);

        if(pixel == Color.WHITE) {
            // Toast here
        }
    }    
}
```